# Export list of elements to .txt file

Tags: list-manipulation, export, code-request

Well, I have the following Mathematica output (as an example):

```
{3,6,7,12,45,67,89,101,349,692}
```

And I am looking for a code that can export this to a .txt file that looks like:

```
1 3
2 6
3 7 
4 12
5 45
6 67
7 89
8 101
9 349
10 692
```

I can not find a way to do this. Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: Modify for your own path: `Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/test.txt", 
 Transpose[{Range@Length@list, list}], "Table"]`

Comment: @BobHanlon I would like to have one space between the two numbers in one row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better way to do it but here is my step-by-step attempt.

```
alist = {3, 6, 7, 12, 45, 67, 89, 101, 349, 692}
blist = Range@Length@alist
clist = Transpose[{blist, alist}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 12}, {5, 45}, {6, 67}, {7, 89}, {8, 
>   101}, {9, 349}, {10, 692}}
> ```

```
elist = (ToString@First@# <> " " <> ToString@Last@#) & /@ clist

Export["C:/testclist3.txt", elist]
```

[image]

---

To import back:

```
flist = Import["C:/testclist3.txt"]
glist = ImportString[flist]
clist == glist (* True *)
```

Another variation could be (as suggested by docs):

```
glist = ImportString[flist, "Table"]
```

but it doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: My pleasure, and thanks for the accept. I would be careful with multi-level lists exported as "Tables". It would be safe to say that I am still learning such exports/imports on a case-by-case basis.